# I want to get the output with 2 decimal numbers

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(xs:Position/xs:Weekly_Hours,'##.##')"/>
```

So if I give it as above, its showing it cannot convert string to integer.

I tried this also , but same

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="xs:Position/xs:Weekly_Hours"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($myVar,'##.##')"/>
```

Comment: Show your `xs:Weekly_Hours` element

Comment: This is a little surprising. In XSLT 1.0 the conversion from string to number will happen automatically. In XSLT 2.0 the same is true, unless your code is written to be schema-aware. If it is written to be schema-aware, then it depends on the schema-defined type of Weekly_Hours: I would expect that to be numeric, but if it's defined as a string, then you need to convert to a number explicitly.

Comment: I would also add that if you want 2 digits after the decimal point, e.g 4.50 or 3.00, then you should use '#.00'. With the format '#.##', you will get no insignificant zeroes. And the initial '#' is redundant.

Comment: @shruthi Obviously, your input is not a number. Perhaps it contains a comma separator, or a currency symbol. We won't know what exactly the problem is and how to solve it until you show it to us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. There was something wrong in XML itself .. So now its resolved

Answer (score 0):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(xs:Position/xs:Weekly_Hours),'##.##')"/>` or if you use XSLT 2.0 or later, instead of `number` you can use another numeric type like `xs:double` or `xs:decimal`.

Comment: I think your parentheses are not quite right in the expression.

Comment: I don't think this will make any difference.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, given the error message "its showing it cannot convert string to integer", it might make the difference. But Michael Kay is right in his comment, the error can only occur if the processing is schema-aware and the item `xs:Weekly_Hours` is defined as a string.

Comment: Perhaps, but that would only apply to XSLT 2.0. And I suspect OP is paraphrasing the error message.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried using number() also, but there was some error in XML itself, now its resolved.. Thanks for reply.